# Am I removing too much paint from exterior when scraping?

Tags: paint, preparation

I am scraping old peeling paint from wood paneling on the exterior of the house. Should I be using a scraper only on the peeling areas while trying not to remove any paint that is not peeling?

I noticed that once I got all the peeling removed from an area, I could still easily get under the edges of the remaining paint with a putty knife and it comes off in huge chunks.

Should all this old paint be removed since it comes off so easily? Or should I only use the scraper on peeling paint and not try to get under the remaining edges with the putty knife?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a subjective question, but ideally any paint that's not well-bonded should be removed. Eventually it'll flake off as well.

That said, there's always a balancing act to be done. You'll have to assess the situation and proceed accordingly. It may not be economically practical to strip the paint entirely, depending on intended lifetime of the siding, etc.

Comment: Right, you can do it now, or do it later.  If two layers are easily separating, it's usually because proper "prep" was not done so the surfaces are not mechanically engaged.  Either the surface had chemical contaminants on it, or was incompatible chemically, or was not scuff-sanded.  As such, prep  the surviving surface carefully  - it gave the previous painter trouble.